# Vertical (rotated) label in Android

Tags: android, label, textview, vertical-alignment

I need 2 ways of showing vertical label in Android:

1. Horizontal label turned 90 degrees counterclockwise (letters on the side)
2. Horizontal label with letters one under the other (like a store sign)

Do I need to develop custom widgets for both cases (one case), can I make TextView to render that way, and what would be a good way to do something like that if I need to go completely custom?

Comment: It is possible to do this in XML as of API 11 (Android 3.0). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774770/sideways-view-with-xml-android

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Here is my elegant and simple vertical text implementation, extending TextView. This means that all standard styles of TextView may be used, because it is extended TextView.

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{
   final boolean topDown;

   public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context, attrs);
      final int gravity = getGravity();
      if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
         setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
         topDown = false;
      }else
         topDown = true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
      super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b){
      return super.setFrame(l, t, l+(b-t), t+(r-l));
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas){
      if(topDown){
         canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
         canvas.rotate(90);
      }else {
         canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
         canvas.rotate(-90);
      }
      canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
      super.draw(canvas);
   }
}
```

By default, rotated text is from top to bottom. If you set android:gravity="bottom", then it's drawn from bottom to top.

Technically, it fools underlying TextView to think that it's normal rotation (swapping width/height in few places), while drawing it rotated.
It works fine also when used in an xml layout.

**EDIT:**
posting another version, above has problems with animations. This new version works better, but loses some TextView features, such as marquee and similar specialties.

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{
   final boolean topDown;

   public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context, attrs);
      final int gravity = getGravity();
      if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
         setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
         topDown = false;
      }else
         topDown = true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
      super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
      TextPaint textPaint = getPaint(); 
      textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
      textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

      canvas.save();

      if(topDown){
         canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
         canvas.rotate(90);
      }else {
         canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
         canvas.rotate(-90);
      }


      canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

      getLayout().draw(canvas);
      canvas.restore();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Kotlin version:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.text.BoringLayout
import android.text.Layout
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.Gravity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
import androidx.core.graphics.withSave

class VerticalTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    private val topDown = gravity.let { g ->
        !(Gravity.isVertical(g) && g.and(Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM)
    }
    private val metrics = BoringLayout.Metrics()
    private var padLeft = 0
    private var padTop = 0

    private var layout1: Layout? = null

    override fun setText(text: CharSequence, type: BufferType) {
        super.setText(text, type)
        layout1 = null
    }

    private fun makeLayout(): Layout {
        if (layout1 == null) {
            metrics.width = height
            paint.color = currentTextColor
            paint.drawableState = drawableState
            layout1 = BoringLayout.make(text, paint, metrics.width, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 2f, 0f, metrics, false, TruncateAt.END, height - compoundPaddingLeft - compoundPaddingRight)
            padLeft = compoundPaddingLeft
            padTop = extendedPaddingTop
        }
        return layout1!!
    }

    override fun onDraw(c: Canvas) {
        //      c.drawColor(0xffffff80); // TEST
        if (layout == null)
            return
        c.withSave {
            if (topDown) {
                val fm = paint.fontMetrics
                translate(textSize - (fm.bottom + fm.descent), 0f)
                rotate(90f)
            } else {
                translate(textSize, height.toFloat())
                rotate(-90f)
            }
            translate(padLeft.toFloat(), padTop.toFloat())
            makeLayout().draw(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution disables links in `TextView`. Actually links are underlined, but not responding on click.

Comment: Hey Mice, Great solution thanks, please can you explain what the fixes do in the fixed version. Much appreciated. M

Comment: Has someone experimented problems on top and bottom padding?

Comment: Intentional, because we're rotating.

Comment: @mice, consider comment for onMeasure like:   use superclass measurement and switch the width/height measures

Comment: No, that's how the trick is made to work. Think a bit about it.

Comment: this has issues with multiline and scrollbars.

Comment: sorry for my basic question, If I got a TextView (in an XML file) and I want to rotate it, how do I have to call VerticalTextView class?

Comment: @blackst0ne instead of <TextView> tags, use a custom view tag: <com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.VerticalTextView>

Comment: can't create view programatically, tou don't have a constructor only with context

Comment: not works in listview, some text can not be displayed in view

Comment: The latest code is good. When creating a VerticalTextView in .xml file, you can add some values as: android:width="150dp", android:layout_height="150dp", android:ellipsize= "end", android:maxLines="1". If text is a long text, it will show 3 points (...)

Comment: works great, in my case I had to extend **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView** instead of **TextView** to make my style attribute working

Comment: When I have a string like this "Value: 20%", the percentage and number are always drawn overlapped each other. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: got this exception with androidx
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed
VerticalTextView.java:44

Comment: How we can achieve in kotlin?

Comment: After putting android:rotation="270" its working but its taking the space of horizotal view also

Comment: This does not work. text is not shown in full..ellipse is shown

Answer (score 32):

I implemented this for my [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/) project. Create `VerticalLabelView.java`:

```
public class VerticalLabelView extends View {
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private String mText;
    private int mAscent;
    private Rect text_bounds = new Rect();

    final static int DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = 15;

    public VerticalLabelView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initLabelView();
    }

    public VerticalLabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initLabelView();

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.VerticalLabelView);

        CharSequence s = a.getString(R.styleable.VerticalLabelView_text);
        if (s != null) setText(s.toString());

        setTextColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.VerticalLabelView_textColor, 0xFF000000));

        int textSize = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.VerticalLabelView_textSize, 0);
        if (textSize > 0) setTextSize(textSize);

        a.recycle();
    }

    private final void initLabelView() {
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
        mTextPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        mText = text;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTextSize(int size) {
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(size);
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        mTextPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), text_bounds);
        setMeasuredDimension(
                measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec),
                measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text
            result = text_bounds.height() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();

            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        mAscent = (int) mTextPaint.ascent();
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text
            result = text_bounds.width() + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float text_horizontally_centered_origin_x = getPaddingLeft() + text_bounds.width()/2f;
        float text_horizontally_centered_origin_y = getPaddingTop() - mAscent;

        canvas.translate(text_horizontally_centered_origin_y, text_horizontally_centered_origin_x);
        canvas.rotate(-90);
        canvas.drawText(mText, 0, 0, mTextPaint);
    }
}
```

And in `attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="VerticalLabelView">
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="textColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Very useful. Here is a link to the trunk version of your project http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/source/browse//trunk/core/src-achartengine/org/achartengine/view/VerticalLabelView.java

Comment: Not useful, text is not shown fully.. its cut off from the end and start.

Comment: Worked in above android version 28 also

Comment: Your version is the best option for my project but setTextColor is not working, also I would like to apply an style (background and fontFamily) is it posible to do it?

Answer (score 13):

Tried both of the VerticalTextView classes in the approved answer, and they worked reasonably well.

But no matter what I tried, I was unable to position those VerticalTextViews in the center of the containing layout (a RelativeLayout which is part of an item inflated for a RecyclerView).

FWIW, after looking around, I found yoog568's VerticalTextView class on GitHub:

https://github.com/yoog568/VerticalTextView/blob/master/src/com/yoog/widget/VerticalTextView.java

which I was able to position as desired. You also need to include the following attributes definition in your project:

https://github.com/yoog568/VerticalTextView/blob/master/res/values/attr.xml

Comment: I found this implementation to be really easy!

Comment: It ignores compound drawables

Answer (score 9):

One way to achieve these would be:

1. Write your own custom [view and override onDraw(Canvas).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) You can draw the text on the canvas and then rotate the canvas.
2. Same as 1. except this time use a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and draw text using [drawTextOnPath(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

Comment: So before I go that route (I looked at onDraw method for TextView - it's massive) I noticed that whole difference between TextView and extending Button is an internal style ID (com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle) Would it be possible to simply define a custom style and extend TextView similar to Button?
I'm guessing that the answer would be no since it's probably not possible to style text to layout verticaly

Comment: Does this approach actually work?  I haven't had success and neither has this guy... http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2009-11/msg02810.html

Comment: 2. drawTextOnPath() draws the text like it was rotated, same as 1. 
To write letters one under the other, either use `\n` after each character or if you have a fixed-width font, limit the TextView width to fit just one character.

Answer (score 3):

There are some minor things need to be pay attention on.

It depends on the charset when choosing the rotate or the path ways. for example, if the target charset is English like, and the expected effect looks like,

```
a
b
c
d
```

you can get this effect by drawing each character one by one, no rotate or path needed.

[image]

you may need rotate or path to get this effect.

the tricky part is when you try to render charset such like Mongolian. the glyph in the Typeface need to be rotated 90 degree, so drawTextOnPath() will be a good candidate to use.

Comment: How can it be done other wayaround for from leftSide to RightSide

Comment: textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL) or textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL) may work above the API level 17. you may test it.

Comment: smart and simple

Answer (score 3):

```
check = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.check);
check.setRotation(-90);
```

This worked for me, just fine. As for the vertically going down letters - I dont' know.

Comment: but it even takes the space horizontally, and rotate it vertically

Answer (score 2):

You can just add to your TextView or other View xml rotation value. This is the easiest way and for me working correct.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_view_qr_code"
    android:layout_above="@+id/text_view_savva_club"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Дмитриевский Дмитрий Дмитриевич"
       android:maxLines="2"
       android:id="@+id/vertical_text_view_name"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#B32B2A29"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vertical_text_view_phone"
        android:text="+38 (000) 000-00-00"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Following [Pointer Null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907695/pointer-null)'s answer, I've been able to center the text horizontally by modifying the `onDraw` method this way:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
    textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
    canvas.save();
    if(topDown){
        canvas.translate(getWidth()/2, 0);
        canvas.rotate(90);
    }else{
        TextView temp = new TextView(getContext());
        temp.setText(this.getText().toString());
        temp.setTypeface(this.getTypeface());
        temp.measure(0, 0);
        canvas.rotate(-90);
        int max = -1 * ((getWidth() - temp.getMeasuredHeight())/2);
        canvas.translate(canvas.getClipBounds().left, canvas.getClipBounds().top - max);
    }
    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
    getLayout().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

You might need to add a portion of the TextView measuredWidth to center a multilined text.

Answer (score 0):

I liked @kostmo's approach. I modified it a bit, because I had an issue - cutting off vertically rotated label when I set its params as `WRAP_CONTENT`. Thus, a text was not fully visible.

This is how I solved it:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VerticalLabelView extends View
{
    private final String LOG_TAG           = "VerticalLabelView";
    private final int    DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = 30;
    private int          _ascent           = 0;
    private int          _leftPadding      = 0;
    private int          _topPadding       = 0;
    private int          _rightPadding     = 0;
    private int          _bottomPadding    = 0;
    private int          _textSize         = 0;
    private int          _measuredWidth;
    private int          _measuredHeight;
    private Rect         _textBounds;
    private TextPaint    _textPaint;
    private String       _text             = "";
    private TextView     _tempView;
    private Typeface     _typeface         = null;
    private boolean      _topToDown = false;

    public VerticalLabelView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        initLabelView();
    }

    public VerticalLabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        initLabelView();
    }

    public VerticalLabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initLabelView();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public VerticalLabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initLabelView();
    }

    private final void initLabelView()
    {
        this._textBounds = new Rect();
        this._textPaint = new TextPaint();
        this._textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        this._textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        this._textPaint.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
        this._textSize = DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE;
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this._text = text;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void topToDown(boolean topToDown)
    {
        this._topToDown = topToDown;
    }

    public void setPadding(int padding)
    {
        setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    }

    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        this._leftPadding = left;
        this._topPadding = top;
        this._rightPadding = right;
        this._bottomPadding = bottom;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTextSize(int size)
    {
        this._textSize = size;
        this._textPaint.setTextSize(size);
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTextColor(int color)
    {
        this._textPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTypeFace(Typeface typeface)
    {
        this._typeface = typeface;
        this._textPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        try
        {
            this._textPaint.getTextBounds(this._text, 0, this._text.length(), this._textBounds);

            this._tempView = new TextView(getContext());
            this._tempView.setPadding(this._leftPadding, this._topPadding, this._rightPadding, this._bottomPadding);
            this._tempView.setText(this._text);
            this._tempView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, this._textSize);
            this._tempView.setTypeface(this._typeface);

            this._tempView.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            this._measuredWidth = this._tempView.getMeasuredHeight();
            this._measuredHeight = this._tempView.getMeasuredWidth();

            this._ascent = this._textBounds.height() / 2 + this._measuredWidth / 2;

            setMeasuredDimension(this._measuredWidth, this._measuredHeight);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (!this._text.isEmpty())
        {
            float textHorizontallyCenteredOriginX = this._measuredHeight / 2f;
            float textHorizontallyCenteredOriginY = this._ascent;

            canvas.translate(textHorizontallyCenteredOriginY, textHorizontallyCenteredOriginX);

            float rotateDegree = -90;
            float y = 0;

            if (this._topToDown)
            {
                rotateDegree = 90;
                y = this._measuredWidth / 2;
            }

            canvas.rotate(rotateDegree);
            canvas.drawText(this._text, 0, y, this._textPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to have a text from top to down, then use `topToDown(true)` method.

Answer (score 0):

My initial approach to rendering vertical text inside a vertical LinearLayout was as follows (this is Kotlin, in Java use `setRoatation` etc.):

```kotlin
val tv = TextView(context)
tv.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
tv.rotation = 90F
tv.height = calcHeight(...)
linearLabels.addView(tv)
```

[image: approach #1]

As you can see the problem is that the TextView goes vertically but still treats its width as if it were oriented horizontally! =/

Thus approach #2 consisted of additionally switching width and height manually to account for this:

```kotlin
tv.measure(0, 0)
// tv.setSingleLine()
tv.width = tv.measuredHeight
tv.height = calcHeight(...)
```

[image: approach #2]

This however resulted in the labels wrapping around to the next line (or being cropped if you `setSingleLine`) after the relatively short width. Again, this boils down to confusing x with y.

My approach #3 was thus to wrap the TextView in a RelativeLayout. The idea is to allow the TextView any width it wants by extending it far to the left and the right (here, 200 pixels in both directions). But then I give the RelativeLayout negative margins to ensure it is drawn as a narrow column. Here is my full code for this screenshot:

```kotlin
val tv = TextView(context)
tv.text = getLabel(...)
tv.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
tv.rotation = 90F

tv.measure(0, 0)
tv.width = tv.measuredHeight + 400  // 400 IQ
tv.height = calcHeight(...)

val tvHolder = RelativeLayout(context)
val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
lp.setMargins(-200, 0, -200, 0)
tvHolder.layoutParams = lp
tvHolder.addView(tv)
linearLabels.addView(tvHolder)

val iv = ImageView(context)
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.divider)
linearLabels.addView(iv)
```

[image: approach #3]

As a general tip, this strategy of having a view "hold" another view has been really useful for me in positioning things in Android! For example, the info window below the ActionBar uses the same tactic!

For text appearing like a store sign just insert newlines after each character, e.g. `"N\nu\nt\ns"` will be:

[image: store sign example]