# How to Rotate TextView 90 Degrees and display

Tags: android

I am having a situation in Graph page where `LinearLayout` should display the `TextView` with 90 degrees rotated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android checked this and solved my issue

Comment: It is possible to do this in XML as of API 11 (Android 3.0). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774770/sideways-view-with-xml-android

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The fastest and most convenient way is to `Rotate` by `Animation`

use rotate animation on your regular TextView like so.

rotateAnimation.xml:

```
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fromDegrees="0" 
           android:toDegrees="-90"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:duration="0"
           android:fillAfter="true" />
```

Java Code:

```
  TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);       
  text.setText("rotated text here");

  RotateAnimation rotate= (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotateAnimation);
  text.setAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: This is good but not helped me a lot checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android helped me a lot in my cse

Answer (score 71):

Try this::

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:rotation="-95"
                android:text="2" 
                />
```

Comment: FYI. Its need Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >11

Comment: problem in this approach is width size doesn't change. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @abh22ishek I figured a way around the width/height confusion issue. Basically I wrap the TextView in a RelativeLayout with negative margins. I'll post a full answer when I have time.

Answer (score 17):

In android for any new view there is a method called [setRotation(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29) you can use it

```
textview.setRotation(float);
```

but please note that this method is Added in API level 11

so if you want to support it you can use this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {

    RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(oldAngel, newAngel);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    watermarkText.startAnimation(animation);
} else {

    watermarkText.setRotation(progress);
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice.

Comment: I edited the answer for more info

Answer (score 12):

```
 <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/rotated_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alpha=".3"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_capsule"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text="Andrew Coder" />
```

Answer (score 11):

**[SOLVED]** After a year of this being on my bucket list without any suitable answers on the forums I have finally sorted this!

The trick here is to hard-code the layout_width and layout_height of the `TextView` larger than the text will ever be - e.g. 100dp x 100dp.

Then place the `TextView` in a `FrameLayout` and turn clipping off for the `FrameLayout`  `android:clipChildren="false"` and clip to padding off for the TextView `android:clipToPadding="false"`:

[`TextView` with hard-coded height and width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ctSJ.png)

The `TextView` will now float in the `FrameLayout`. Use the `TextView` gravity settings to move the Text within it's boundary.

Then use the layout_gravity settings to move the boundary within the parent `FrameLayout` within it:

Here is an example of right and bottom aligned text rotated through -90 degrees:

[Solution example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CExDv.png)

**[UPDATE]** Example XML for a frame view housing rotated text:

```
       <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/item_col_width_val"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:padding="@dimen/table_header_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/table_title_row_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/table_title_row_height"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:rotation="-90"
                android:text="@string/asm_col_title_in_stock"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGood" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your xml code so we can more quickly understand your explanation of your answer.

Comment: @ProgDevCode added some XML as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need animation then you can try a solution provided in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46646273/1808829). A text will be written from bottom to top.

It supports all basic TextView features:

- text size
- text color
- text font
- text padding
- usage via XML

Main point is to override `onDraw()` and `onMeasure()` methods based on parameters of your text:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (!this._text.isEmpty())
        {
            float textHorizontallyCenteredOriginX = this._measuredHeight / 2f;
            float textHorizontallyCenteredOriginY = this._ascent;

            canvas.translate(textHorizontallyCenteredOriginY, textHorizontallyCenteredOriginX);
            canvas.rotate(-90);
            canvas.drawText(this._text, 0, 0, this._textPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        try
        {
            this._textPaint.getTextBounds(this._text, 0, this._text.length(), this._textBounds);

            this._tempView = new TextView(getContext());
            this._tempView.setPadding(this._leftPadding, this._topPadding, this._rightPadding, this._bottomPadding);
            this._tempView.setText(this._text);
            this._tempView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, this._textSize);
            this._tempView.setTypeface(this._typeface);

            this._tempView.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            this._measuredWidth = this._tempView.getMeasuredHeight();
            this._measuredHeight = this._tempView.getMeasuredWidth();

            this._ascent = this._textBounds.height() / 2 + this._measuredWidth / 2;

            setMeasuredDimension(this._measuredWidth, this._measuredHeight);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

Please, take a look at [Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android/46646273#46646273) to see the full source code.