# Display or set Text Diagonal way to textview

Tags: android

will it be possible to display text in diagonal way if yes then how can we implement, please help me out for this thanks.
i have added image i have to replace WORLD text with other text.

[image]

Comment: its better if your use image with already written text.

Comment: i have to set text as todays date which is not a good idea to put 365 images inside application..:(

Comment: agreed,but rotation won't works for all versions.

Comment: yes that why i created custom text view class its working well with 4.0 os and also test on 2.3 OS working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [How to Rotate TextView 90 Degrees and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959069/how-to-rotate-textview-90-degrees-and-display).

The easiest way to do this is to:

1. Create `TextView` with your background image.
2. Rotate `TextView` as it is done in link above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using API 11 or later, you may try:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
String txt = "Stackoverflow";         
tv.setText(txt);
tv.setRotation(45); // 45 degree rotation
```

Try this..

Comment: setRotation support api 11 and more i have to support from 8

Answer (score 0):

Use android:rotation in XML

or

textView.setRotation(angle)

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3arotation)

Answer (score -1):

Guys i have implemented with custom textview thanks for your valuable response.working well on 4.0 device need to test it on 2.2 device.

```
    public class DiagonalTextView extends TextView{
   final boolean topDown;

   public DiagonalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context, attrs);
      final int gravity = getGravity();
      if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
         setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
         topDown = false;
      }else
         topDown = true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
      super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b){
      return super.setFrame(l, t, l+(b-t), t+(r-l));
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas){
      if(topDown){
         canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
         canvas.rotate(45);
      }else {
         canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
         canvas.rotate(-45);
      }
      canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
      super.draw(canvas);
   }
}
```

Comment: while not mandatory, I believe it is a goodwill to value the original writer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19834048/1567541