# Android Rotate a textview around a specific point

Tags: android, rotation, textview

Is it possible to rotate a textview around a special point ?

`tv.rotate(float x)` doesn't offer this option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959069/how-to-rotate-textview-90-degrees-and-display

Comment: thats a simple rotation around the midpoint of the view...

I want to rotate the textview around a specific point (x,y) like i can do with imageViews

Comment: That's what `android:pivotX` and `android:pivotY` are doing... The `50%` is used to center the pivot. Just move the value. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotX%28float%29