# Rotation for TextView

Tags: android

I have a simple view with included `TextView` on `RelativeLayout`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:rotation="-20"
/>
```

and it works well on slider view, but when I'm trying to include it to list adapter it has gone.

I tried to wrap this `TextView` to `LinearLayout` and set it programmatically, but it hasn't helped.

How can I rotate my view? What is it a sort of problem? Thank for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959069/how-to-rotate-textview-90-degrees-and-display

Comment: I think that should work on any layout but try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't need animation, just static rotated view

Comment: you need add setTranslationX, setTranslationY to pull textview to screen

Comment: @mdtuyen it hasn't helped. "android:rotation" makes view disappear

Comment: rotation make center of view is pivot as default, so that some position of view can move out of screen.