# AnimationSet cannot be cast to RotateAnimation

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation, classcastexception

(Newbie's problem)
The snippet of my code looks like:

```
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation= (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.clockwise_anim);
```

and the clockwise_anim.xml located in res/anim looks like:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="5000" >
    </rotate>
</set>
```

and I've got an error excactly on this snippet above:                                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException:

> android.view.animation.AnimationSet cannot be cast to
>   android.view.animation.RotateAnimation

I saw such code many times and I don't get what goes wrong in my case. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I saw such code many times* where? Obviously you cannot cast object of type RotateAnimation to AnimationSet. It's basic OOP rule. As AnimationSet is not derived from  RotateAnimation.

Comment: For example:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959069/how-to-rotate-textview-90-degrees-and-display)

Comment: Not true as root XML in that case is rotate not set. Also answer is bad as there is no need to cast at all... As loadAnimation returns Animation and setAnimation take Animation as parameter.

Comment: Ok, I didn't suppose it could be the problem. It's my first time with animation. Many thanks for your time

Comment: Remove cast and replace type to Animation...