# how to get changes on data automatically when data on sever is changed

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, android-studio, android-layout

hi hope you are all doing well.
i am facing a problem with with my app. I am using server to store the data of my app and i want to keep check on data changes.
Mean when i add any data in the database then be get noticed and then update data in list view. I am using API written in php for data getting from server.
That's it.
plz if anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more details, which alignment which textview

Comment: This two questions are similar to your question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959069/how-to-rotate-textview-90-degrees-and-display, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:rotation="270"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="dummy text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```