# How to rotate text of the Button in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I want to rotate the text on the button, but I could not do it all day.

I tried Custom Vertical Button but it is not centering the text in the button. I tried all gravity options in java and xml code.

[image]

Here is my VerticalButton code:

```
public class VerticalButton extends Button{

    public VerticalButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint(); 
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
        canvas.rotate(-90);

        canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
        getLayout().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

I tried rotate Button with `android:rotation="-90"`

That didn't work the way I wanted. Because it is not editing the background size.

[image]

I tried Relative Layout with Button and TextView but I couldn't bring the TextView over the Button

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your xml file plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I edited the onDraw function. Firstly get width and height of text with `getTextBounds()`

In `getTextBounds()` give the the text of your Button as parameter.

And edit the `canvas.translate()` function like below. And it is centering the text in the button.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
    textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds("ENTER",0,"ENTER".length(), bounds);

    Log.e("TAG", "onDraw: "+ bounds.width() + " "+bounds.height());
    canvas.save();

    canvas.translate(getWidth()/2 - bounds.height(), (float) (getHeight()/2 + bounds.width()/1.5));
    canvas.rotate(-90);

    getLayout().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try one of these two:

[Is it possible to write vertically in a textview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android/17001995)

[Sideways View with XML Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774770/sideways-view-with-xml-android)

Allegedly, you can set the rotation property in xml, like in last one and it may work. I didn't try it out, hope you will find success with this. Since you tried with -90, try setting an degree to 270

Comment: I did try them but not working. Thank you for answer. I published the solution

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is set button text as `"E\nN\nT\nE\nR"`

Comment: Characters won't rotate then.