# write text vertically on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to display text vertically on `Canvas`.
Please help me.

Comment: A little search does not hurt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android Google also gives pretty good information ...

Comment: Using a vertical textview and drawing text vertically on a canvas are different things.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a Path object that defines the verticle line you want your text to follow. Then use a canvas.drawTextOnPath() method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
Canvas canvas;
canvas.rotate(90);
canvas.drawText("The text", 0, 0, new Paint());
```