# Could I write text vertically as in japanese script, is it possible at all?

Tags: android, text

I want to write text vertical, but not to rotate it - example:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

Could be this done in some specific way in android or I should add a new line after each and every letter of the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only writing a few things have each letter on its own line may be easier. You can use `/n` after every character to have each letter move to a different line. I am unfamiliar with a way to do ith without rotation unless you make a vertical textview that can only fit one letter per line(width = very small)

This old SO post may give you some more insight if you are intereted in doing it this way. (It does involve rotation)

[Write Vertical on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076914/write-text-vertically-on-canvas)

This tutorial was linked to on the above SO post

[Tutorial](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1625)

Comment: So there is now other way and I should add a new line!?? 10x

Comment: @nenito nothing that I know(accept a very small width and make the textview vertical :), someone else will weigh in in a bit I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not averse to a bit of JavaScript post-processing, this will do what you want:

```
<html>      
<head> 
   <title>Vertical Text</title>
   <style>
   .vert { 
      width: 0;
      display: inline-block;
   }
   </style>   
</head>
<body>
<span class="vert">this is a test</span> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function (d) {
      var s = d.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');  
      for (var i = 0, n = s.length; i < n; i = i + 1) {  
         if (s[i].className === 'vert') {  
            var h = s[i].innerHTML; 
            var t = '';
            for (var j = 0, k = h.length; j < k; j = j + 1) { 
               if (h[j] === ' ') {   
                  t = t + '&nbsp;'
               } else {
                  t = t + h[j];
               }     
               if (j < k - 1) { 
                  t = t + ' ';
               }   
            }
            s[i].innerHTML = t;
         }
      }
   }(document));  
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```