# Showing edittext obliquely in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I have an EditText, which generally shows parallel to the screen X-axis. I want to show it obliquely (around 45 degree to horizontal axis). Is it possible to do this in Android. Please guide me in a direction so that I can try for it.

After getting the two links in the answer by pawelzeiba, I proceed a little bit in solving this, but stuck again so I put another question on this. here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035976/creating-oblique-edittext-in-android).

As Gunnar Karisson said, there is a **setRotation()** method in **View** class introduced in **Android 3.0**, but I cannot use it as my application should work fro **Android 2.1** version.

So please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long R & D, I succeed to solve this by creating my own custom edittext, which works perfectly as per my requirement.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

private Animation rotateAnim;
public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}

private void createAnim(Canvas canvas) {
        rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, -45, 250, 50);
        rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // creates the animation the first time
        if (rotateAnim == null) {
                createAnim(canvas);
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) is an indirect subclass of [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) which has a rotation field you can set with [setRotation(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29):

> myEditText.setRotation(45.0f).

Comment: Gunnar, I cannot use this method as my app should run from Android 2.1 version onward. So I need some solution which could work on Android 2.1 version. See my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate view, examples:

[Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)
[Is it possible to write vertically in a textview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android)

But I'm not sure how it will look with EditText during edition.

Answer (score 0):

If the `setRotation()` method isn't available to the API level you are working with, then your best bet would be to create your own subclass of View and implement a `setRotation()` method.

Comment: Thats what I am asking, I have already implemented but facing some problems in that case. Please see the link given in the question.