# Creating oblique edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a requirement to show an EditText at 45 degree angled to horizontal axis.So I used this code to do this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("Hello");
Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, -45.0f, 190, 90);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
editText.setAnimation(anim);
```

It also shows the EditText as per my requirement. But problem arises when I started typing some text in it.

[image: Screen Shot]

As you can see the screen shot, some places of the edittext are not showing the text and at the middle portion of the edittext is only displaying the text.

The **Hello** which is in the left corner of the edittext is just becase of, I set that using **setText()**

Please help me how to create an edittext obliquely so that I can type properly in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long R&D, I succeed in solving this,

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

private Animation rotateAnim;
public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}

private void createAnim(Canvas canvas) {
        rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, -45, 250, 50);
        rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // creates the animation the first time
        if (rotateAnim == null) {
                createAnim(canvas);
        }

}
}
```

[image: My new working screen shot]