# My own custom textview which can show text vertically, but something wrong! who can help me

Tags: android, textview, overriding, ondraw, vertical-text

I want to extend a VerticalTextView class , It can make the content show vertical text.
example: 
`android:text="Hello"`
It shows like:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

I try to override the onDraw function. Code below:

```
public class VerText extends TextView {
public VerText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VerText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public VerText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
    textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    String textString = (String) getText();
            //textString = "Hello";
    for (int i = 0; i < textString.length(); i++) {
        canvas.drawText(textString.charAt(i) + "", getMeasuredWidth() / 2
                - getTextSize() / 2, (i + 1) * getTextSize(), textPaint);
    }
    getLayout().draw(canvas);
}
```

}
It is very simple,right?
I got problem here,when I use

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <com.example.testmycustom.VerText
        android:id="@+id/verText1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and make `//textString = "Hello";` useful,It works well,
However when I use

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <com.example.testmycustom.VerText
        android:id="@+id/verText1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Hello"//!!!!only added this one!!!! and canceled comment textString="Hello"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There show two hello! One is vertical , the other is horizontal.Could anybody tell me why? Thx! Some new method to achieve this target welcomes.

Comment: What is this?  `getLayout().draw(canvas);`  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: If delete getLayout().draw(canvas),It will not be shown.you can have a try~

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong.  Please show your onCreate() and edit your XML so it is *exactly* what you are using with no comments.  You do not need to draw the canvas to the control, that's what onDraw is for, you are overriding the super class.

Comment: I created a new project just for testing my custom textview, onCreate() is just setContentView(...).

Comment: I think my onDraw function is wrong

Comment: So debug it.  Put a breakpoint on the canvas.drawText line.  Are all of the values correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12433475/961759) out. It uses a Path to draw the text instead of a loop.

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final ColorStateList csl = getTextColors();
        final int color = csl.getDefaultColor();
        final int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();
        final int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
        final int viewWidth = getWidth();
        final int viewHeight = getHeight();
        final TextPaint paint = getPaint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        final float bottom = viewWidth * 9.0f / 11.0f;
        Path p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(bottom, viewHeight - paddingBottom - paddingTop);
        p.lineTo(bottom, paddingTop);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(getText().toString(), p, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a test, I added getLayout().draw(canvas); after canvas.drawTextOnPath(getText().toString(), p, 0, 0, paint); Two 'hello' appear (one vertical one horizontal), Why this happen.

Comment: Hard to tell without your current code. Are you sure you only have one VerticalTextView on your layouts/code ?

Comment: Yes i am sure. You can have a try,add getLayout().draw(canvas);  after canvas.drawTextOnPath .

Comment: Why are you doing that? isn't that exactly the problem ?

Comment: @daimajia you probably call `base.OnDraw()`

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
package artefatoscs.util;
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b){
        return super.setFrame(l, t, l+(b-t), t+(r-l));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){

        canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
        canvas.rotate(-90);

        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

res\values\attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="VerticalLabelView">
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="textColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

your.xml

```
<artefatoscs.util.VerticalTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="2sp" />
```