# Vertical TextView taking too much space in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create something like the following using LinearLayout and TableLayout:

[image]

I am stuck on Vertical Text, though. It is taking more space than it should take after rotation.

The following is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_CONSEQUENCES"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:text="CONSEQUENCES"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>
         <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>
         <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the output is like this:

[image]

The vertical text is taking more space than it should need, and not all of the text is appearing. :(

Comment: Take a look at that post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android

good luck

Comment: The accepted answer is the duplicate I just flagged. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 20):

You can use code below:

```
android:rotation="270"
```

Comment: this cause whole TextView including its background to be rotated, this might not be desirable

Comment: Yes, So the best way is Custom TextView vertical.
You can use this example I've search on google: http://www.pocketmagic.net/2010/12/android-vertical-textview-custom-angle-text/
I hope help you :)

Comment: it still takes that extra space

Comment: @Prabs add minus margin values to remove extra space. like `android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"`

Answer (score 14):

None of the solutions worked for me but I found this blog post by Mark Allison:
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/verticaltext-part-1/

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView
{
    final boolean topDown;

    public VerticalTextView( Context context, 
        AttributeSet attrs )
    {
        super( context, attrs );
        final int gravity = getGravity();
        if ( Gravity.isVertical( gravity )
            && ( gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK ) 
            == Gravity.BOTTOM )
        {
            setGravity( 
                ( gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK )
                    | Gravity.TOP );
            topDown = false;
        }
        else
        {
            topDown = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, 
        int heightMeasureSpec )
    {
        super.onMeasure( heightMeasureSpec, 
            widthMeasureSpec );
        setMeasuredDimension( getMeasuredHeight(), 
            getMeasuredWidth() );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
    {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.setColor( getCurrentTextColor() );
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

        canvas.save();

        if ( topDown )
        {
            canvas.translate( getWidth(), 0 );
            canvas.rotate( 90 );
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.translate( 0, getHeight() );
            canvas.rotate( -90 );
        }

        canvas.translate( getCompoundPaddingLeft(), 
            getExtendedPaddingTop() );

        getLayout().draw( canvas );
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

The rotation is done by the gravity. So be sure to set this in your xml:

```
<com.stylingandroid.verticaltext.VerticalTextView
    style="@style/verticalTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:text="@string/text" />
```

Comment: Incase the view looks like change     android:gravity="bottom|right"  to     android:gravity="bottom|center"

Comment: its crashing on android Pie.    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed

Answer (score 1):

```
    val textPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    textPaint.textSize=toPx(16)
    textPaint.color=Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
    canvas.save()
    canvas.translate(50F, 60F)
    canvas.rotate(90F)
    canvas.drawPaint(textPaint)
    canvas.drawText("YourText", 0F,0F, textPaint)
    canvas.restore()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack to create vertical text view.
So the scenario was I need to show a static tag on the right side of the screen.
so I just used "\n" for the new line as my text was less.

> android:text="A\nC\nT\nI\nO\nN"

You can check the image I've attached. although it's not suggested if you showing data from Dynamically. 
[image]

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_action"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="126dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red_left_rcorner"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="A\nC\nT\nI\nO\nN"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/drawer_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end|center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the Text view in Linear Layout and try to give proper Layout weight to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in .xml file just put

```
<TextView> 
 android:layout_width="wrap content"
 android:layout_height="wrap content"
 android:rotation="270"
</TextView>
```

Answer (score -1):

why not put padding?so it will go in the center of your screen.just try it out if you like

Answer (score -2):

If you want to reproduce your image I would use a GridView or a TableLayout with no buttons, just set the proper listeners if you need to do any action. This way you can set fixed heights and widths.