# Why the vertical TextView taking different spaces -android-

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview, vertical-text

I have a TextView inside CardView. after rotation (-90 or 270), each textView had different space from ImageView

The result is like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad9r1.jpg)

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="123456789"
    android:rotation="-90"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_item"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

I tried to put the TextView inside LinearLayout but the output is the same.
if there any solution (using just XML) please tell me.

i found this on stackoverflow :
[Vertical TextView taking too much space in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059877/vertical-textview-taking-too-much-space-in-android)
but the result is the same and  i am looking for solution using XML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `layout_height` to `0dp` and modified the `layout_constraint`, like the code below:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/number"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="123456789"
android:rotation="-90"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_item"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_item"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_item"/>
```

Now, no matter the length of the text, it will be attached to view next to it.