# How to remove extra space in vertically rotated textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I created an activity which shows TextView as vertically.  There is extra space after the textview.  How can remove the extra space.  The follow below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_mode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AppMod"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:background="@drawable/text_border"
            android:onClick="onAppModeChange"
            android:clickable="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbViewsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tb_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Line 1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tb_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:text="Line 2"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tb_3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:text="Line 3"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you rotate the witdh still the same you have some options

1. You can use a library to use a [`Rotate Layout`](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout)
2. You can change the width of your `TextView`and add the desired to fit your `textSize`
3. Create a custom [`VerticalTextView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512310/4385913) or [`VerticalTextView`](https://github.com/yoog568/VerticalTextView)
4. Remove the rotation and add this as text `android:text="A\np\np\nM\no\nd\ne\nl"`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/tbViewsLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

remove paddingLeft attribute from the second linear linear layout