# Vetical textview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

i want vertical `TextView` in my application. I reffered [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)
 how to use it for my `TextView`

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtmenuCaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtmenuName"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:text="you can browse. select and place online orders"
        android:textColor="#e6e6e6"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should do as you saw in the example and `Override` the `TextView` class and then if you want to declare in xml the class you should replace TextView with path to custom text view (the path i wrote is just an example so you should use your path here):

```
 <com.path.to.custom.textview
    android:id="@+id/txtmenuCaption"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtmenuName"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:text="you can browse. select and place online orders"
    android:textColor="#e6e6e6"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```