# Rotated TextView in RelativeLayout with Margin - TextView still behaviour like if it's not rotated

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to do something like the image below, where I have a rotated (90°) `TextView` with `marginLeft` related to the `ImageView`. The problem is, when I increase the `TextView` value, say 2 to 2000000, it move to the right, behaving like a non-rotated `TextView` (see the blue square around it). How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_note"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/drawing_flange" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_dimC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:text="Ø1200"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_dimd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:text="Ø200000000000"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_dime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:text="300"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_dimf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:rotation="0"
    android:text="75"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_dimg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_flange"
    android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:rotation="0"
    android:text="130"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post your current xml for this layout?

Comment: I've tried to rotate programmatically (using `TextView.setRotation(90)` and even using `animation` but it doesn't work as well.. I searched everywhere and I can't find a solution, I'm almost using it in the horizontal (default) orientation but, as the `marginLeft` is related to the left side of the TextView boundary (the "blue box" in the image around the text) I can't keep the text centered in the line.. I can't believe that there isn't a way to fix it..

Comment: I see. You are better of writing a custom TextView that updates its bounds as well. Refer this for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android/17001995#17001995

Comment: Thank you @MuchOverflow, I'll have a look on that!

Comment: @MuchOverflow it worked! Finally! Please answer the question and I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you rotate your TextView using `android:rotaion` in xml or `myTextView.setRotation()` in the Java code, the bounds of the text view will not update to the angle you rotated the text view into. To overcome this you may write a custom `TextView` that draws itself in the correct angle you require it to. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android/17001995#17001995) answer for a starting point.