# Vertical Textview in Android

Tags: android, textview

I have my screen, which is divided in the 4 parts vertically and I want vertical text in all the 4 strips, I tried using `android:rotation="-90"` but if my text is long it is appearing in the 2 lines. How can I make it only in 1 line.

I want DELHI AGRA in only line

[image]

Following is my xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/offers_view">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:background="#CC4D9E59"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:text="Delhi Agra"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_xxxmedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:rotation="-90"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:background="#CC9C27B0"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Goa"
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_xxxmedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:rotation="-90"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_lmedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:background="#CC2196F3"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:text="Delhi"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_xxxmedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:rotation="-90"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_lmedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/fourth"
            android:background="#CCFF9800"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/view_all_cities"
                android:text="@string/view_all_cities"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_xxxmedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:rotation="-90"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_lmedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does `android:singleLine="true"` not work?

Comment: No, after adding this only DELHI is getting displayed

Comment: And did you set the width to be `wrap_content`?

Comment: yes, I have set both width and height to wrap_content

Comment: OK, try setting the width to `match_parent`. Also make sure that you don't have a `\n` between DELHI and AGRA.

Comment: Actually every strip width is fixed so if textview width is more than strip's width than it is appearing in 2 lines

Comment: Then this is your problem (and you already know why: `so if textview width is more than strip's width than it is appearing in 2 lines`). Please try as per my comment above on the `DELHI AGRA` TextView. They don't need to have the same width - only the height (which is divided in 4 equal parts).

Comment: I tried that but it is not working, Please try to understand my point I want screen to be divided into 4 strips and if the number of characters in the textview width is more than strip's width than it is appearing in the 2 lines but what I want is it should appear in single line as I have enough vertical space.

Comment: Well, if you think that I'm confusing between width and height; no, I'm not. Because I'm taking in account the **90° rotation**.

Comment: No no,I am not saying that.

Comment: Then, `android_width="match_parent"` with no `singleLine` should work just fine. Unless you have `\n` characters in between your words.

Comment: I have posted my xml layout, please tell me now

Comment: OH NO!! Why all those inner LinearLayouts?!

Comment: Wait a minute... I'll correct that for you.

Comment: Maybe AGRA doesn't appear because it would be off the screen

Comment: `android:rotation="-90"` applies _after_ measurement. The text may be drawn vertically, but the TextView itself still has its width (before rotation) constrained by the parent (so at most one quarter of the screen), and _then_ it is rotated. I don't think you can achieve the effect you want without writing a custom View, or extending TextView and making it measure and draw itself differently.

Comment: No, it didn't work. My last attempt was to apply the rotation to the container (set as vertical instead of horizontal). The only good result was in landscape mode, but it left some white paddings on the left and right sides. In practice, the overall width equated the height (something very "squarish"). Really odd. As @Karakuri noted, you may need to create a custom View.

Comment: check my answer it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/76260233/4264996

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/offers_view">

        <com.example.app.views.VerticalTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:text="Delhi Agra"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_large"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#CC4D9E59"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_lmedium"/>

        <com.example.app.views.VerticalTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Goa"
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_large"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:background="#CC9C27B0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/logo_size"/>

        <com.example.app.views.VerticalTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:text="Delhi"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_large"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:background="#CC2196F3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_lmedium"/>

        <com.example.app.views.VerticalTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_all_cities"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/view_all_cities"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_large"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:background="#CCFF9800"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Follow this for `VerticalTextView` [Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)