# How to display a text vertically or rotate a TextView in layout XML file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-controls

I want to display a string vertically in a view as below, is there have a way to implement that in layout XML file?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android/7855852#7855852

Comment: have little fun with this tricky code.. **yourTextView.setRotation(-90);**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To rotate the textview in xml use : android:rotation="-90"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:rotation="-90"/>
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo8rN.png)

Answer (score 1):

add attributes in Text view android:rotation="-90"

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```