# Android: i wanna to make recyclerView in landscape mode and all the app in prtrait mode

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i have issue is that i wanna to creat table in landscape mode while the activity in portrait mode so i think that i can make it with rotated recyclerView 
XML here

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

and java

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        recyclerView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(height, width));
```

so in the case i have rotated recyclerView but isn't in ther place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on the link below should help you achieve your goal if am getting you right.

[Is it possible to write vertically in a text view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888892/9476848)

Use the same trick to get your effect. Just replace the textView with your recycler view

Happy coding.

Comment: The answer in the link you have provided explains it better... 
In which case I presume it is going to be a lot of work for you to manipulate it...
I have tried the solution in a sample application and my solution works but it would take a lot more work to handle the events afterwords as he sites above

Answer (score 1):

If you want a horizontal `recyclerView` in your layout you just have to set the layout manager as `LinearLayoutManager` and the second parameter to `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

This will result in a `recyclerView` that is horizontaly scrollable in a vertical layout.

Comment: If I understand the question properly, this is not the effect he is looking for....  and if he used this approach, he'd not be able to create recycler view items in landscape to achieve a landscape table

Comment: i don't mean that in my question how to make recyclerView scroll horizontaly ; but i wanna to rotate the view

Comment: Can you please attach an image for reference?