# Put rotated text on an imageview

Tags: android, xml, textview, imageview

Hi i need to put some text over an imageview.

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/bg"
/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEST"
/>
```

But this doesnt displays the text only the picture. And also I have to rotated this text. Is this even possible with TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the default TextView implementation that allows you to rotate the text. You will have to create your a custom view. Take a look at this question: [Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android).

In that case, I think it'd be much easier to modify the bitmap representation of the `ImageView` and add the rotated text (which you can do using the `Canvas` methods like rotate, restore, etc... you can easily find information about that on Google).