# Android: Library projects and styleable resources

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an application that I now want to split part of off into a library project so I can re-use it in several other places.  Among the stuff in there being re-used is a custom view, which uses code from this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android) with some adaptations I made to it.  Anyway, the styleable resources don't work properly.  The attr.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="VerticalTextView">
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="textColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="rotateLeft" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and it's referenced in a layout file in the library project.  I get the following error in Eclipse when trying to compile the main project:

[2010-12-20 23:29:38 - MyApp] C:\Library\res\layout\main.xml:124: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'text' in package 'com.mydomain.mylibrary'

I'm puzzled.  I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work, and I just haven't found the magic combination.  How do I make styleable resources work inside of a library project?

Comment: i guess its too late but have u looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471742/android-library-project-uses-declare-styleable-how-to-compile

Comment: It's a bit late for this project, but in the future, I'll give that a try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have failed all attempts to get this working in a library package earlier this month and eventually gave up.  To remedy the situation I just added the source files as 'linked' (still external from the project and shared) and this has been working for me.

Comment: Well, apparently this just doesn't work.  I found a thread talking about this here:  http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fc9ac9f168a2ec4f/33ac0c1a69e8d86c?lnk=gst&q=library+project+attr&pli=1

Answer (score 6):

The issue has been fixed in ADT 17:
to use custom styleables defined in a library project, you have to use the *http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto* namespace, so, considering the example from the question:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ... >
    ...
    <com.foo.bar.VerticalTextView
        custom:textColor="#cafebabe"
        custom:rotateLeft="true"
        ... >
```