# Is it possible to have two different Resource folders in Android development?

Tags: android

I use the widget DateSlider provided by http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/
However, it also has its own resource files, I wonder how I can separate those resource files from mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up an Android library project for that slider and include the library into your own project.

Take a look at the [library project documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)

Comment: I do as the instruction. However, when I "Referencing a library project", it report error like this `\DateSlider_release\res\layout\timeslider.xml:13: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'childWidth' in package 'com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider'` and all my file has error `R can not be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Hey, I tried that and I can reproduce the error. There seems to be some issue with styleable resources. I never had styleables in my libs, so I never got that before. Here is a question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471742/android-library-project-uses-declare-styleable-how-to-compile I tried to fix it, but nothing I know works for me (even the solution from that question). I recommend opening a new question, so people who may know a solution can see it.