# Flipping the TextView horizontally

Tags: android, text, textview

How do I flip *TextView* horizontally in android (Not looking for suggestions using anything other than a TextView). The text should appear as if it is seen through the mirror. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I haven't yet spent a lot of time with Android on a UI level, but in Java I'd look at overriding the paint method and doing some sort of paint; rotate; paint; trick... something similar maybe could work here...

Comment: yes, writing a custom TextView overriding onDraw() seems the only way, but it shouldn't be that hard if you only need to draw text. TextView.onDraw() doesn't look that simple, you could look for some vertical text example, it's a similar problem.

Comment: for vertical text look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this will work, but it seems like it should. Try using the AndroidCharacter.Mirror() method described here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/AndroidCharacter.html

Comment: Nope, didn't work. May be this works only for certain fonts that have mirror characters. I also tried the AndroidCharacter.mirror(char[], int, int) but didn't work :-( Thank you for your time Matt.

Comment: It's alright dude. Good luck with this, I'll keep trying to think of possible solutions.