# Android -- Is there a way to rotate a toast 90 degrees?

Tags: android, user-interface

Can't think of any more info to provide. Is there a way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As *hackbod*  said, you would have to have a custom view to display the toast.

I found a few classes for you that rotates the label for you: [`VerticalLabelView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android/2599518#2599518) and [`CustomTextView`](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1625)

I chose to use the latter, and had this code working in my own app:

```
// Creating a new toast object
Toast myToast = new Toast(MyActivity.this);
// Creating our custom text view, and setting text/rotation
CustomTextView text = new CustomTextView(MyActivity.this);
text.SetText("Hello World!");
text.SetRotation(-90, 120, 90);
myToast.setView(text);
// Setting duration and displaying the toast
myToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
myToast.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an easy way.  You can supply your own view to display the toast, so you can make a view that rotates its content.