# Rotate Android toast

Tags: android, rotation, toast

I'm trying to rotate Android toast using next code:

```
public static void ShowToast(){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This is toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    View toastView = toast.getView();
    toastView.setRotation(90);
    toast.setView(toastView);
    toast.show();
}
```

But toast doesn't rotate. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for response.

Comment: Give this answer a go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234575/469080

Comment: @MichaelDodd Thank you! And sorry for bad googling :(

Answer (score 0):

**customtoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);**

```
  public void showCustomToast(String fname, String lastName) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
//        View customToastroot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycustom_green_toast, null);
        View customToastroot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_login, null);

        GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) customToastroot.findViewById(R.id.GifImageView);
        TextView tv_title = (TextView) customToastroot.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        TextView tv_message = (TextView) customToastroot.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);

        gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.mipmap.valid_1);
        tv_title.setText("Success!");
        tv_message.setText("Welcome " + fname + " " + lastName);

        Toast customtoast = new Toast(context);
        customtoast.setView(customToastroot);

//        customtoast.SetRotation(-90, 120, 90);


        //customtoast.setText("Authentication Done");
//        customtoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0, 0);
        customtoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);
        customtoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        customtoast.show();
//        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_in);
    }
```