# Android - How to have Mixed Orientation Tabs? (some tabs portrait, others landscape)

Tags: android, layout, tabs, orientation

I have created an app with multiple tabs, each with its own layout. I have shut down response to the accelerometer to keep the app in portrait mode (android:screenOrientation="portrait").

Two of the tabs are designed in portrait mode, and one tab is designed in landscape mode. I need to take advantage of the fact that the screen is wider than it is high in landscape to display a mini spreadsheet.

Here is my question: How do I orient one of the tabs to landscape, while leaving the other two in portrait mode?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution outside of the tab-set. The following link discusses multiple solutions for displaying *Vertical* text:

[Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)

I went with "CustomTextView" by PocketMagic which can be found here: http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1625

With the ability to display vertical text, I can keep the entire tab-set locked in Portrait mode.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

-cc

Answer (score 3):

To programmatically change orientation use setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); or setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);. In this case each tab click event could be tied to its relevant orientation

source: http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/solved-set-screen-orientation-programmatically/

Comment: This will effect the tabset as a whole, won't it? For this application I need the tabs to stay at the top (in portrait mode) and not shit to the right (landscape) when the phone is rotated.

Is there a way to only rotate the layout inside of a tab, without rotating the entire screen?

Comment: If you have a method for each tab forcing it to the orientation you want, it will always have the correct orientation for the actively selected Tab.

Comment: No. This had the predicted result. The frame set rotated alone with everything else placing the tabs at the top of the screen in landscape mode. What I need is the ability to rotate the _Contents_ of a single tab to landscape mode, or the ability to _Lock_ the tabs in place at the top of the portrait oriented screen.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you got an answer yet, but I've been searching for 30 mins and found a solution to a similar problem.  Hope this helps.

I'm using tabhost and want 3 of 4 tabs to be able to rotate and 1 tab set to portrait mode only.  Previously (before applying this fix) the 3 tabs would rotate until the fixed portrait tab was selected, then they were all stuck in portrait mode.

I had to set the other tabs to use the orientation of the USER to remedy this.  i.e. added a `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);`  in the onResume of the other 3 tabs and it now works exactly as I had intended.  3 tabs will now rotate based on the user's orientation of the device, and 1 tab is fixed portrait.  :)