# Android: Orientation Change Only on One Tab?

Tags: java, android, orientation, android-tabhost

I'm using a tabhost with three tab widgets, each hosting a View.

I want only one of those tabs to react to an orientation change.

I've tried registering for `configChanges` on the Activity and overriding the `onConfigurationChanged(..)` method.  I then detected orientation using Display measurements and used `setRequestedOrientation(..)` to change it.

It seem `setRequestedOrientation(..)` only works once, then all other calls to it are ignored.

Any ideas how to do this?

***Note***: I'd rather not use Activities for each tab 1. because it wastes system resources and 2. I've tried it already and couldn't get this to work on that method either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701000/android-how-to-have-mixed-orientation-tabs-some-tabs-portrait-others-landsc) may have several adequate answers to your question. One involves having a listener change the orientation on each tab click
 and the other involves using `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);`