# Android - Locking tabs to portrait orientation

Tags: android, tabs, orientation, landscape

I am writing an Android app with three tabs, two designed in portrait mode, and one (a mini-spreadsheet) in landscape mode. The issue is with the function of the tab-set. When I set the orientation in the landscape tab, the tabs themselves move over and take up the top of the screen. This takes up a large portion of the screen space, and is confusing to the user.

Here is my questions: How do I lock the tabs themselves in place, so they stay in the same position when in landscape mode; in landscape mode this would be the left side of the screen.

Another way of approaching the question: Is there a way to rotate a layout inside of a tab without effecting the entire tab-set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution outside of the tab-set. The following link discusses multiple solutions for displaying *Vertical* text:

[Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)

I went with "CustomTextView" by PocketMagic which can be found here: http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1625

With the ability to display vertical text, I can keep the entire tab-set locked in Portrait mode.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

-cc

Answer (score 0):

in the manifest under the tab activity, put android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: That would work if I was only interested in changing the screen orientation for the entire app. What I am trying to accomplish is more complex. I want the tabs from the tab set to stay in one place regardless of the current orientation. Or... I want to rotate the orientation of a layout inside of a tab without effecting the tab-set (again keeping the tabs in one place)