# rotating a TextView and remeasuring in Android

Tags: android, textview, rotation

I'm trying to create a vertical textview with the following code

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{

public VerticalTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.i("VerticalTextView", "onDraw Called");
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(-90, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    super.setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());

}



}
```

however I'm finding that it is not redefining the full width in the new height. and therefore the texts is really truncated.

Any ideas? 
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android) (look at kostmo answer not the accepted one), he uses two custom methods to compute the size of the View (`measureHeight` and `measureWidth`).

So `super.setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());` looks wrong according to his answer.

It seems you can as well copy/paste his answer, I think it is what you are trying to achieve.