# How to set TextView programatically like in this image?

Tags: android

I just want to set text programatically like in this image. Please help me to get this  landscape screen TextView:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.inbox);
}
```

[image: image 1]

Comment: [Take a look at this.](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1625)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855852/413127

'Vertical Text' is what you want to google for

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{
   final boolean topDown;

   public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context, attrs);
      final int gravity = getGravity();
      if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
         setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
         topDown = false;
      }else
         topDown = true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
      super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b){
      return super.setFrame(l, t, l+(b-t), t+(r-l));
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas){
      if(topDown){
         canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
         canvas.rotate(90);
      }else {
         canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
         canvas.rotate(-90);
      }
      canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
      super.draw(canvas);
   }
}
```

Comment: <VerticalTextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"                    android:textColor="@color/green"           
 android:text="Activation"/>is it right way to access like this

Comment: No you need to add your package to the XML declaration.  <com.you.package.VerticalTextView />

Comment: yes i did its working thaks..now i have ttf file for font how to set type face for this text

Comment: Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"MS-I034.TTF"); 
       textPaint.setTypeface(face); is it right