# How to make a TextView Text vertical

Tags: android

I want a vertical label for my app. Is there a property to make text vertical? Here's what I mean vertical label:

```
S
t
a
c
k
o
v
e
r
f
l
o
w
```

thanks ahead.

Comment: You might need to do it your self by extending a view or textview and overriding the onDraw method.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution may be to insert a `\n` after each character, and make sure that the the height is set to `fill_parent`.

Comment: thank you, it works. I also have a solution, in setting textView text i use Html.fromHtml(), and I traverse every letter and insert <br/> tag then set the textView Text.

Answer (score 1):

Add \n after every letter. In the layout xml it won't appear right, but running it to an actual device or emulator will appear correct.

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="h\ne\nl\nl\no\n w\no\nr\nl\nd" />
```

you can set the layout_height to wrap_content as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also another option if you only need one line of text and have a fixed-width typeface (monospace or Asian fonts):

Limit the TextView width to fit just one character. The height can be wrap_content.