# Have can I arrange vertically the text of the TextView in Android

Tags: android, imageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android).
>   [How to make a TextView Text vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117094/how-to-make-a-textview-text-vertical)

Have can I  arrange vertically the text of the TextView.Just like the follow picture,sorry,I am no allow to posting my image!

Comment: upload your sample image....

Comment: You can use this custom class [VerticalTextView](http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/source/browse/trunk/src/com/jwetherell/augmented_reality/widget/VerticalTextView.java?spec=svn127&r=123)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="a\nn\nd\nr\no\ni\nd" />
```

Try this.
put \n after each character.

Answer (score 0):

You can override setText method of the TextView, and can insert \n between each character. As following example:

```
public void setText(CharSequence str)
{
    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
          buffer.append(str.charAt(i));
          buffer.append("\n");
     }
     buffer.setLength(buffer.length()-1);
     super.setText(buffer.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it.I think I should overwrite the TextView so that it can arrange vertical its text.

Answer (score 0):

solution given by others are absolutely perfect but there is a other way

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="2sp"   /* width of one character width*/
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="a\nn\nd\nr\no\ni\nd" 
    android:singleLine="false"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android