# Vertical Text android

Tags: android, textview, orientation

I know that this question was asked before but i'm using it in widget so i can't make a custom class (such as VerticalTextView).

Any idea how can i make it using xml?

Answer (score 0):

Really in widget, I think there is only one way - try to use `rotate`. [Similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855852/1616443). Hope it's help.