# Is possible to do this with a TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in Android and before to try some code I would like to know if what I want to do is technically possible with a TableLayout:

1. Each table cell has different type of content: some cells just text, other ones text and image, others just image, etc..
2. Catch events for each individual cell (catch double tab, long tap,...)
3. Build MxN tables (I guess it shouldn't be a problem)
4. Set different color or style for each row or an individual cell
5. Write vertical text in a cell
6. Add borders to each cell or just some selected cells
7. Add diagonal scrolling

Are all these points technically possible with tablelayouts?

Comment: Why not try? Make a demo project and try them out. It won't take long.

Comment: @Ata Because sometimes someone has tried it before and it is not technically possible with Android. But sure that if no one knows I will give a try.

Comment: I know, but we usually like to see some code tried out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Each table cell has different type of content: some cells just text, other ones text and image, others just image, etc..**

You can put any view in cells. It can be LinearLayout, Text, Images.

**Catch events for each individual cell (catch double tab, long tap,...)**

You can put any clickable view (LinearLayout) inside cell as host for other views

**Build MxN tables (I guess it shouldn't be a problem)**

Yes

**Set different color or style for each row or an individual cell**

Yes, but a view and set background.

**Write vertical text in a cell**

[Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android/7855852#7855852)

**Add borders to each cell or just some selected cells**

Yes, put a LinearLayout and set the borders for it

**Add diagonal scrolling**

[Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)