# Transform android button text vertically/downwards

Tags: android, button, text

I have a button with text moving horizontally like so:

```
My Buttons Text
```

I'm trying to have the button's text move downwards like so:

```
M
y
.
.
.
```

Comment: See this tut: [Tutorial][1]
Note: Just change TextView to Button

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android/7855852#7855852