# How to add String Label to MPAndroidCharts

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am developing a simple Android app which shows a dataset of flot numbers on a linechart.
I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and thanks to it I am able to manage my custom linechart and its style.

However, I am trying to add a String Label in order to label both the domain (x-axes) and the range (y-axes) of my linechart, as shown in the picture below.
[image: example]

Any suggestions to do it using MPAndroidChart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what I need it is not supported by the MPAndroidChart.
Hence the only way to do that is to define two `TextView` for domain and range label respectively.
Moreover, in order to have the range label as shown in the above figure I suggest to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android/7855852#7855852) which explain how to design a vertical `TextView`. It works for me.