# MPAndroidChart - Adding labels to bar chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

It is necessary for my application to have a label on each bar of the bar chart. Is there a way to do this with MPAndroidChart? I could not find a way to do this on the project wiki/javadocs.

If there isn't a way to do this is there another software that will allow me to?

[image]

Comment: See below answer [Adding Axis Titles to MpAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56456415/5157605)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Updated Answer (MPAndroidChart v3.0.1)**

Being such a commonly used feature, v3.0.1 of the library added the [`IndexAxisValueFormatter`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/IndexAxisValueFormatter.html) class exactly for this purpose, so it's just one line of code now:

```
mBarChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
```

The **ProTip** from the original answer below still applies.

**Original Answer (MPAndroidChart v3.0.0)**

With v3.0.0 of the library there is no direct way of setting labels for the bars, but there's a rather decent workaround that uses the `ValueFormatter` interface.

Create a new formatter like this:

```
public class LabelFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    private final String[] mLabels;

    public LabelFormatter(String[] labels) {
        mLabels = labels;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return mLabels[(int) value];
    }
}
```

Then set this formatter to your x-axis (assuming you've already created a `String[]` containing the labels):

```
mBarChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new LabelFormatter(labels));
```

**ProTip:** if you want to remove the extra labels appearing when zooming into the bar chart, you can use the granularity feature:

```
XAxis xAxis = mBarChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

Comment: can you provide me some decent source code on how to show multiple bar graph with labels on the xAxis

Comment: you proTip saved my day. Thanks! @TR4Android

Comment: Thanks for keeping your answer up to date. This question gets asked a lot so we should redirect duplicates here

Comment: My X axis values are appearing at the top of the chart's X axis, I want it to show in the bottom X axis.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @neo Try `mBarChart.getXAxis().setPosition()`. For more information check the javadocs [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/XAxis.html#setPosition-com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis.XAxisPosition-).

Comment: @TR4Android would the above code still work for labels that are String values?

Comment: @neo Actually, that code works exclusively with string values.

Comment: The above code sets the column label at the top of the chart.  How would I go about adding an extra label into the center of each bar?

Comment: @TR4Android , can you help me on this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690661/mpandroid-group-bar-chart-is-not-showing

Comment: Thanks, although this does work but now it's skipping one label after each item in the arraylist of string, unless i zoom horizontally.

Comment: I have even tried to reduce the text size of x-axis labels by binding.barChart.getXAxis().setTextSize(8); but the issue still persists.

Comment: @eCDroid Have you tried forcing the labels to all display by setting `barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(labels.length, true)`?

Comment: Tried but now the labels messed up and still doesn't show all.

Comment: Okay now barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(labels.length, false) with passing false as force, the labels does display. Another problem, the labels are far from the bottom of the bars how to move them closer. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to make the labels appear for every single bar?  I'm using the 3.0.1 version, but it is only showing labels along the Xaxis for every other bar...  I already tried .setLabelCount(labels.length), both with true and false options.

Answer (score 10):

you can set the column label above by adding this line

```
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 7):

**For version of implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'**

you can set labels with below snippet.

```
final ArrayList<String> xAxisLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    xAxisLabel.add("Sun");
    xAxisLabel.add("Mon");
    xAxisLabel.add("Tue");
    xAxisLabel.add("Wed");
    xAxisLabel.add("Thu");
    xAxisLabel.add("Fri");
    xAxisLabel.add("Sat");


    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);

    ValueFormatter formatter = new ValueFormatter() {


        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            return xAxisLabel.get((int) value);
        }
    };

    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // minimum axis-step (interval) is 1
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use IndexAxisValueFormatter to make things easier.

```
final String[] labels = new String[] {"Dummy", "Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May",
    "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```