# How to make graph of data which is stored in firebase database?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, graph, mpandroidchart

I am trying to add [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to my app by using the following code, but i am getting an error on

> **BarData barData =  new BarData(xData, barDataSet);** ------this line

and the error is

```
 BarData in BarData cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList <java.lang.String>,
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet)
```

How to resolve this error, please help

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/slabo.ttf");
        myTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
        barChart = (BarChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        float yValues [] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        String xValues [] = {"first", "second", "third", "four", "five"};
        drawBarGraph(yValues,xValues);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void drawBarGraph(float yValues[], String []xValues){
        ArrayList<BarEntry> yData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++){
            yData.add(new BarEntry(yValues[i],i));
        }
        ArrayList<String> xData = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++){
            xData.add(xValues[i]);
        }
        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(yData, "Cells");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarData barData =  new BarData(xData, barDataSet);
    barData.setValueTextSize(13f);
    barData.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    barChart.setData(barData);
    barChart.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I like MPCharts: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: @Juan can you help me with the implementation of this library with firebase

Comment: I can help answering doubts you may have, but you have plenty examples here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample

Comment: @Juan i am trying to solve the above conflict, can you please help me so that it can be implemented successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think you are passing in the `(x,y)` data the other way round. It should be  `Data.add(new BarEntry(i, yValues[i]));`

2) You are passing in two parameters for `BarData`. It shouyld be only one.

```
barData =  new BarData(barDataSet);
```

3) For the labels use an `IAxisValueFormatter` and set the granularity between labels to the 1f which is the difference between the X axis values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) used when setting the `BarEntry`s.

This is an example code based on your code, the examples in [MPCharts GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), and [this question on setting the labels for BarChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857038/mpandroidchart-adding-labels-to-bar-chart)

```
public class ChartsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BarChart barChart;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chart_layout);

        barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);

        float yValues [] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        String xValues [] = {"first", "second", "third", "four", "five"};

        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        drawBarGraph(yValues,xValues);

    }

    private void drawBarGraph(float [] yValues, String [] xValues){
        ArrayList<BarEntry> yData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++){
            yData.add(new BarEntry(i,yValues[i]));
        }


        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(yData, "Cells");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);


        BarData barData =  new BarData(barDataSet);

        barData.setValueTextSize(13f);
        barData.setValueTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new LabelFormatter(xValues));
        barChart.setData(barData);
        barChart.invalidate();
    }



    public class LabelFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
        private final String[] mlabels;

        public LabelFormatter(String[] labels) {
            this.mlabels = mlabels;
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return mLabels[(int) value];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but i think there is an error in this code, the `private final String[ ] labels;`  should be replaced with `private final String[ ] mLabels`
and `this.labels = labels;`  should be `mLabels = labels;`

but thanks a lot again i really appreciate it.