# MPAndroid Group bar chart is not showing

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

Here is the code i used for group bar_chart using MPAndroid library version 3. I've tried group bar chart in lower version and it works fine but the BarData constructor is changed in latest version. And this code doesn't works. There is no crashes and error logs, still graph is loading and no data shows in it. Help me to find ma flaws

```
        List<BarEntry> entriesGroup1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<BarEntry> entriesGroup2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<BarEntry> entriesGroup3 = new ArrayList<>();

        entriesGroup1.add(new BarEntry(0, 8f));
        entriesGroup1.add(new BarEntry(1, 2f));
        entriesGroup1.add(new BarEntry(2, 5f));
        entriesGroup1.add(new BarEntry(3, 20f));
        entriesGroup1.add(new BarEntry(4, 15f));
        entriesGroup1.add(new BarEntry(5, 19f));

        entriesGroup2.add(new BarEntry(0, 6f));
        entriesGroup2.add(new BarEntry(1, 10f));
        entriesGroup2.add(new BarEntry(2, 5f));
        entriesGroup2.add(new BarEntry(3, 25f));
        entriesGroup2.add(new BarEntry(4, 4f));
        entriesGroup2.add(new BarEntry(5, 17f));

        entriesGroup3.add(new BarEntry(0, 9f));
        entriesGroup3.add(new BarEntry(1, 1f));
        entriesGroup3.add(new BarEntry(2, 15f));
        entriesGroup3.add(new BarEntry(3, 13f));
        entriesGroup3.add(new BarEntry(4, 40f));
        entriesGroup3.add(new BarEntry(5, 25f));

        BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(entriesGroup1, "Group 1");
        BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(entriesGroup2, "Group 2");
        BarDataSet set3 = new BarDataSet(entriesGroup3, "Group 3");

        final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("2016");
        labels.add("2015");
        labels.add("2014");
        labels.add("2013");
        labels.add("2012");
        labels.add("2011");
        IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {

            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

                if((int) value < 0 || (int) value >= labels.size()){
                    return "";
                }else{
                    return labels.get((int) value);
                }
            }

            // we don't draw numbers, so no decimal digits needed
            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {  return 0; }
        };

        set1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#cd5080"));
        set2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0d5080"));
        set3.setColor(Color.parseColor("#fc5080"));;

        float groupSpace = 0.06f;
        float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
        float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset
// (0.02 + 0.45) * 2 + 0.06 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"

        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // minimum axis-step (interval) is 1
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);

        BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2, set3);
        data.setBarWidth(barWidth); // set the width of each bar
        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.groupBars(2016, groupSpace, barSpace); 
        barChart.invalidate(); // refresh

        barChart.animateY(5000);
```

**Nb: I'm edited my current question since i'm banned to ask new questions. But its important for me. Thanks everyone.**

Comment: @Nilu i've seen this answer. my project has almost 87 activity pages, so does it required to edit in all activies to include onPause and onResume? Or any alternate way?

Comment: check this https://tips.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-how-to-check-if-the-app-is-in-background-or-foreground/

Comment: `... almost 87 activity pages ...` Holy crap! Why so many Activities, whereas you could use Fragments and only one (or a few) Activity(es)?!

Comment: @NoiseGenerator that much views are in this app

Comment: `that much views are in this app` ... one Activity per View? That would be really crazy!

Comment: @NoiseGenerator sounds crazy too for me when i first met with this project. already completed client project by another development team. doing bug fix on that. now you understand why i required these kind of questions.

Comment: You should tell your customer that since the app was poorly written (to be kind), it has to be **totally reengineered**, from A to Z.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator , thats what i'm thinking right now. Can you help me on another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693717/how-to-open-inactive-app-activity-from-notification-click?noredirect=1#comment82346608_47693717

Comment: Throw in the question, let's see who can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Application` class and add counter of foreground activities, if counter is `0` means your `activity` is in background

```
class MyApp extends Application{
 public int foregroundActivities  = 0 ;

 @override
 public void onCreate(){
     super.onCreate();
     this.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
                    foregroundActivities++;
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
                    foregroundActivities--;
                }
        }
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer your question, Application class is singleton to Lifecycle so you can register Activity Life cycle call backs as above which will be triggered by all your 87 activities.

Suppose,
If any of your 87 `activities` is started, it will call `onActivityStarted()` method, where the count of foreground activity will become `1`, if `activity` is closes, it will call `onActivityStopped()` which will decrement count of foreground activities back to `0`.

So you can detect whether application is in foreground or background based on counter,

```
if(applicationInstance.foregroundActivities > 0){
    //App is in foreground
 }else{
    //App is in background
 }
```

Comment: I've already has an application class. in oncreate, it looks new to me. can you explain the flow of this code.

Comment: I've added description stating the function of activity lifecycle call back in application class

Comment: ok thanks. one more doubt about it,  what if when i'm finishes the last activity and return to previous activity? does it mark as count 0 or  1?

Comment: as long as any activity is on screen, count will not be 0, if count = 0, it means all the activities are in background

Comment: thanks @rajanks. i'll reply back after implented on ma app

Comment: thanks for your valuable time. i've changed question since i'm banned from asking new question. And its important doubt for me now, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is not my answer, i have seen this ques before and impleneted in my app it worked like a charm. Couldn't find the link to the original answer so i am posting the code that i used.
You can use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks :

```
public class AppTransitionStatus implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

private static final long MAX_BACKGROUND_TIME = 2000;
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask task;
private boolean isBackground;

private final Transition transition;

private void goToForeground(Activity iActivity) {
    transition.appToForeground(iActivity);
}

private void goToBackground() {
    transition.appToBackground();
}

private void stopTimer() {
    if (task != null) task.cancel();
    if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
}

public AppTransitionStatus(@NonNull Transition transition) {
    this.transition = transition;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    if (isBackground) {
        goToForeground(activity);
    }
    stopTimer();
    isBackground = false;
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    timer = new Timer();
    task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            isBackground = true;
            goToBackground();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, MAX_BACKGROUND_TIME);
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

}

public interface Transition {
    void appToForeground(Activity iActivity);

    void appToBackground();
}
}
```

And then you can register this in your application class

```
 registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AppTransitionStatus(new AppTransitionStatus.Transition() {
        @Override
        public void appToForeground(Activity iActivity) {

            Log.d("Transition", "App in Foreground");

        }

        @Override
        public void appToBackground() {
            Log.d("Transition", "App in Background");
        }
    }));
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable time. i've changed question since i'm banned from asking new question. And its important doubt for me now, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use blow code :

```
    public boolean isActivityRunning(Context context) {
   boolean isActivityFound = false;
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> activitys = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < activitys.size(); i++) {
        if (activitys.get(i).topActivity.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.Your_Activity_Name}")) {
            isActivityFound = true;
        }
    }
    return isActivityFound;
}
```

here com.example.testapp is your package name

need to add the permission to your manifest..

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

it returns u activity running or not by using name on it and also change as your requirement .

**UPDATE**

```
public static ArrayList<ActivityInfo> getAllRunningActivities(Context context) {
try {
    PackageInfo pi = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pi.activities));

} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

This method give u list of all running activitys in your project

Comment: does it work for full application?

Comment: yes it works for any class to detect running or not

Comment: What is this one used for "ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.Your_Activity_Name}". i need to add all activity names here right? But i need an alternate solution.

Comment: no just pass string name of activity any it returns result

Comment: thanks for your valuable time. i've changed question since i'm banned from asking new question. And its important doubt for me now, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the activity `hasWindowFocus()` boolean method. Then if it has focus you display a pop-up from the activity, if not, you just display the notification.

Comment: it doesn't works fine for me. thanks

Comment: thanks for your valuable time. i've changed question since i'm banned from asking new question. And its important doubt for me now, hope you can understand.