# mpandroidchart bar chart, how to know the x value from y value?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

my problem is how to know or define the other(couple) value of the y-axis or x-axis.
My code :

```
  formatterValueY = new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getAxisLabel(float valueY, AxisBase axis) {
                //how to find the valueX of valueY ??
                // need it to return string 
                //note: I know the search solution(data loop 
               //search),
                // it is useless if there is two equal values y1=y2
      
                //this is example of what I wanna achieve,
                // this is simple example,
                
               float x = findTheRealXOfY(valueY);
               //or
               //float x = findTheRealXOfY(valueY,axis);

               if(x %2==0)
               {
                    return "Pair:"+valueY;
                 }
               else{
                  return "inPair:"+valueY;
                }

                
            }
        }


        YAxis yAxis = myBarChar.getYAxis();
        yAxis.setValueFormatter(formatterValueY);
```

so if there is way to find the real pair value of Y using the valueY and axis.

This is an example of what I want

[image: example chart]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe if you added a more concrete example of why you want this people could suggest approaches. Normally the y axis labels on a chart would be independent of the x values.

Comment: @TylerV done dude check out the simple example.

Comment: You didn't answer why do you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: There could be multiple x values for a given y value though (or none at all, axis labels are not tied to data points). Why would you want to put this in the y axis labels at all? Maybe add a simple picture of what you want the chart to look like and why you need this? If you want labels on individual points there is a better way of doing that, not using the y axis labels.

Comment: @RickyMo it is clear dude the value "string" of y depend in the value of x, example : lets say it 7day bar chart (in X axis) and so if the day position is pair the y value should be = to "Rest" and the other unpair days should be = to "Work", this is only simple example.

Comment: @MehdiS you are only telling "what" you want to do, not "why" you want to do. Your proposed solution may or may not be the best approach to solve your actual problem. That's why people ask for "why" you want to do this. There maybe other approaches to suit your actual needs. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @TylerV the Y value depend on X value, I am using ValueFormatter for x label because the entries "data" of the bar chart are <id,number> pairs, I need to know the id of the Y value so I decide what to return according to it is "id". example : if (id == BOY_ID) return valueY+"/BOY" else  return valueY+"/Girl". I think it is clear now with this example. I am here for any other information

Comment: @RickyMo I already told you because the value of y depend of the value of Y, it is bar chart no line chart, and bar chart each bar has <X,Y> values. example: the X is Id the Y is Float value but I to add some text to it like (boy / girl)

Comment: The axis labels are independent of the data shown on the plot, so what you are asking for still makes no sense. Please add a picture to the question showing what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like maybe you are confused about what an axis label is.

Comment: Also, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857038/mpandroidchart-adding-labels-to-bar-chart)

Comment: @TylerV  sorry dude for the bad explanation but here is picture===> https://ibb.co/Lr9JDWc . the boy/girl mean the majeure voter  for the color.

Comment: @RickyMo please read my last comment with a picture, it is example of what I need.

Comment: @TylerV I know that solution you provided but it not what I need, because "float value" are the number of people voted for that color, and it can be +10K vote so that solution not logic at all.

Comment: Ok, the picture helps - but why doesn't `mBarChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));` work for you? If you have the data you set on the chart, you can prepare an array of labels based on their values.

Comment: @TylerV I told you in the last comment x working 100% the y value not working

Comment: @TylerV I found  it after 2day of search, read my solution.

Comment: @RickyMo read my solution I found it.

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer below that shows how to do that already... This would have gone a lot smoother if you had just asked "how do I put labels on top of the bars on a bar chart?"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want these labels you have a couple options. If you want to set the labels along the bottom of the chart, you can use the `IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)` on the x axis. If you want to add labels on the top of the bars you can set a `ValueFormatter` on the `BarDataSet`. Here is an example that sets "L" or "M" on the lower axis depending on the bar height, and "Less" or "More" on the bar label itself - also depending on the bar height.

[image: example app]

For setting the x axis labels, the relevant command is

```
xaxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)
```

and for the bar labels

```
barDataSet.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getBarLabel(barEntry: BarEntry?): String {
        var label = ""
        barEntry?.let { e ->
            // here you can access both x and y
            label = if( e.y > 25 ) {
                "More"
            } else {
                "Less"
            }
        }
        return label
    }
}
```

If you want the labels above the bars, you can use

```
barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true)
```

**Complete Example**

```
val barChart = findViewById<BarChart>(R.id.bar_chart)

// the values on your bar chart - wherever they may come from
val yVals = listOf(10f, 20f, 30f, 40f, 50f, 60f)

val valueSet1 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
val labels = ArrayList<String>()

// You can create your data sets and labels at the same time - 
// then you have access to the x and y values and can 
// determine what labels to set
for (i in yVals.indices) {
    val yVal = yVals[i]
    val entry = BarEntry(i.toFloat(), yVal)
    valueSet1.add(entry)

    if( yVal > 20) {
        labels.add("M")
    }
    else {
        labels.add("L")
    }
}

val dataSets: MutableList<IBarDataSet> = ArrayList()
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(valueSet1, " ")

barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false)
barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false)
barChart.description.isEnabled = false
barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false)


val xaxis: XAxis = barChart.xAxis
xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
xaxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
xaxis.granularity = 1f
xaxis.isGranularityEnabled = true
xaxis.setDrawLabels(true)
xaxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
xaxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)
xaxis.textSize = 15f

val yAxisLeft: YAxis = barChart.axisLeft
yAxisLeft.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
yAxisLeft.setDrawGridLines(true)
yAxisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(true)
yAxisLeft.isEnabled = true
yAxisLeft.textSize = 15f

barChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
barChart.extraBottomOffset = 10f
barChart.extraLeftOffset = 10f

val legend: Legend = barChart.legend
legend.isEnabled = false


barDataSet.color = Color.CYAN
barDataSet.valueTextSize = 15f

// You can also set a value formatter on the bar data set itself (and enable
// setDrawValues). In this you get a BarEntry which has both the x position
// and bar height.
barDataSet.setDrawValues(true)
barDataSet.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getBarLabel(barEntry: BarEntry?): String {
        var label = ""
        barEntry?.let { e ->
            // here you can access both x and y
            // values with e.x and e.y
            label = if( e.y > 25 ) {
                "More"
            } else {
                "Less"
            }
        }
        return label
    }
}
dataSets.add(barDataSet)

val data = BarData(dataSets)
barChart.data = data
barChart.invalidate()
```

Comment: oh big thanks but already found it :D , but thanks so mush. your solution in Kotlin my in Java. the mistake is I was using "getAxisLabel" instead of "getBarLabel", tnx dude

Answer (score 0):

[example of what I needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnmsj.png), this is the best solution, with no over-code

this is the code:

```
BarData data = new BarData(colorBarSet);

data.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {

                @Override
                public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "this is the X value: " + barEntry.getX());
                    Log.e("TAG", "this is the Y value: " + barEntry.getY());

                // this will return "Girl" for red color with x value=1, 
                // value of x is the index of the color in bar chart
                return getMajeureVoteOfColor(barEntry.getX);
                }
            });
```