# Image out of bounds after transformation on view

Tags: android, view, rotation, imageview, bounds

I'm having a problem with displaying my image.

I have an Image I want to display full screen. So I have this Imageview with match_parent and 20dp padding.

[image]

It looks good but when I apply rotation on it, it seems that the bounds of the view doesn't change and the image can get clipped out of the screen ! Totally don't want that to happen! How do I rescale the image so that the image also fits in the ImageView when its 90 degrees rotated.

[image]

This is my XML WITH rotation in it.

[image]

EDIT:

How to fix the bounds of the Image so the Text is aligned just above the image?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rotation is not taken into account when measuring the view and calculating the scale ratio. A possible solution is to do it yourself :

```
public class RotatedImageView extends ImageView {

    ...
    constructors
    ...


    private double mRotatedWidth;
    private double mRotatedHeight;

    private boolean update() {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();

        if (d == null) {
            return false;
        }

        int drawableWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int drawableHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (drawableWidth <= 0 || drawableHeight <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        double rotationRad = getRotation() / 180 * Math.PI;

        // calculate intrinsic rotated size
        // see diagram

        mRotatedWidth = (Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad)) * drawableHeight
                + Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad)) * drawableWidth);
        mRotatedHeight = (Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad)) * drawableHeight
                + Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad)) * drawableWidth);

        return true;
    }


    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        if (update()) {
            double ratio = mRotatedWidth / mRotatedHeight;

            int wMax = Math.min(getDefaultSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE, widthMeasureSpec), getMaxWidth());
            int hMax = Math.min(getDefaultSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE, heightMeasureSpec), getMaxHeight());

            int w = (int) Math.min(wMax, hMax * ratio);
            int h = (int) Math.min(hMax, wMax / ratio);

            setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

    }

    private final float[] values = new float[9];

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (update()) {
            int availableWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
            int availableHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

            float scale = (float) Math.min(availableWidth / mRotatedWidth, availableHeight / mRotatedHeight);

            getImageMatrix().getValues(values);

            setScaleX(scale / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]);
            setScaleY(scale / values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        super.setRotation(rotation);
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

`adjustViewBounds` must be true :

```
<com.mypackage.RotatedImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/test" />
```

A nice explanation of the calculation, courtesy of [Cheticamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414865/image-out-of-bounds-after-transformation-on-view/43477366?noredirect=1#comment74025272_43477366) :

[image]

[image: rotation="0"]

[image: rotation="45"]

[image: rotation="90"]

UPDATE: Now trying to adjust the bounds. There is no difference between `wrap_content` and `match_parent` (both grow as much as possible, based on the image aspect). You should instead use `maxWidth` and / or `maxHeight`, or put it in a `LinearLayout` with a 0 size and a weight.

It is also not animatable, adjusting bounds while animating requires a layout pass for each frame, which is very inefficient. See the other answer for a version usable with `View.animate()`

Comment: looks good, let me try this tomorrow ! will keep you posted !

Comment: Can you tell what formula is that?

Comment: the width (resp height) after rotation depends on both the width and height before rotation, e.g. when rotation = 0 :  sin = 0, cos = 1 so width after = width before (obviously), when rotation = 90 : sin = 1, cos = 0 so width after = HEIGHT before. I'll try to add a more complete explanation tomorrow

Comment: @azizbekian This was such a clever answer that I sat down and figured out what is going on. Here is a link to my calculations for what it is worth. http://i.imgur.com/zZUFpul.jpg

Comment: Works like a charm ! very nice calculations ! just a minor question, can you also make it work with minus degrees like -90? then my feature is complete. Could just check if the value is < 0 and then do + 360, that would be the easy fix, but maybe your method can handle this in a more clever way?

Comment: @Cheticamp, thanks! Look nice! One question I have. I kinda forgot trigonometry after school, how do you clarify that those angles are actually theta?

Comment: @DennisAnderson it does no work with -90 ? The result should be the same as 270

Comment: @Cheticamp thanks for the picture, it's better than what I intended to do, so I have added it to the answer

Comment: @bwt , yes it seems to ignore it. I also have the usecase where when I do view.animate().rotate(90).start(); and its not doing the onMeasure(), what will be your advise? I shall award you with the bounty because this calculation is the answer for the original question ! Triple thanks for that !

Comment: overriding `setRotation()` and calling `requestLayout()` would trigger `onMeasure()`. It is usefull if you want to set the rotation programatically, but not for an animation (doing layout a pass for every frame is horribly slow). Being able to animate the rotation would be very nice, I'll try to find a solution

Comment: @azizbekian Thetas are numbered 1-4 clockwise from left. Vertical dashed lines are parallel. The 1st & 2nd thetas are equal because they are alternate angles (transversal of a parallel lines). The 4th theta is also equal since its triangle is congruent with the 2nd theta's triangle. The 3rd shares an angle with the 4th when added = 90 degree. What I really did to convince myself was to think of the vertical lines as chains dangling and imagining how they would change through a rotation - closed at zero degree rotation and all 90 at 90 degree rotation.

Comment: @DennisAnderson I finally managed to make a version usable with `animate()`. It is quite hackish, so I added it as another answer and left this one as is. I am not sure wich one is the best

Comment: btw small follow-up: adjustViewBounds doesn't do the required function it normally does. The Bounds of the imageView stays at the Height of how the image was after Rotation - is still fixable?

Comment: good point. The bound adjustement is done on the drawable's size before rotation. I'm note sure if there is a simple solution. I'll try to find something

Comment: if you want I can open a new question with bounty on this topic ;) googling everything but can't seem te find the answer.

Comment: I don't have much time right now, but I will look into it this weekend. There is no need for another bounty, at least not for me. I think it is an interesting question and I would really like to get to the bottom of it

Comment: There is a much simplier solution (without support of animation): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355784/android-rotate-whole-layout/21475913#21475913

Answer (score 1):

according to a research leading to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d) i wonder if @Sarge Borsch answer could work in your case.

Try setting

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

If centerInside is not correct because you want display in center, maybe try to position the imageview instead of the image inside.

Another suggestion: your imageview is set on "wrap_content" and i don't know exactly the order of everything but maybe the problem comes because it rotates after calculating dimensions (because of wrap_content). I think it is a possibility because the screenshoot you put shows that the image is not even fitting the width. TL;DR : try to fix the imageview size (padding on activity + match_parent) instead of wrap content, in combination of "adjustViewBounds".

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the RotatedImageView which rotation can be animated with a `ViewPropertyAnimator`. The idea is the same, but the scaling is done in `onDraw()` instead of `onMeasure()`, so it does not need a layout pass each time.
In order to make the animation work, I had to hijack the update listener. If you want to use your own listener, don't forget to `invalidate()` the view in `onAnimationUpdate()`.

```
public class RotatedImageView2 extends ImageView {

    ...
    constructors
    ...

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int beforeWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int beforeHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        int max = Math.max(beforeWidth, beforeHeight);

        // try to grow
        setMeasuredDimension(getDefaultSize(max, widthMeasureSpec), getDefaultSize(max, heightMeasureSpec));
    }


    private final float[] values = new float[9];

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable d = getDrawable();

        if (d == null) {
            return;
        }

        int drawableWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int drawableHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (drawableWidth <= 0 || drawableHeight <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        double rotationRad = getRotation() / 180 * Math.PI;

        double rotatedWidth = (Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad)) * drawableHeight
                + Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad)) * drawableWidth);
        double rotatedHeight = (Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad)) * drawableHeight
                + Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad)) * drawableWidth);

        int availableWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int availableHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        float scale = (float) Math.min(availableWidth / rotatedWidth, availableHeight / rotatedHeight);

        getImageMatrix().getValues(values);

        setScaleX(scale / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]);
        setScaleY(scale / values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        super.setRotation(rotation);
        // force redraw
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewPropertyAnimator animate() {
        // force redraw on each frame
        // (a ViewPropertyAnimator does not use setRotation())
        return super.animate().setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Use example :

```
<com.mypackage.RotatedImageView2
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/test" />
```

Comment: Dude ! I love the effort you took into this to answer my questions ! I'm going to try this one out very soon ! :D thanks man ! will let you know if it worked !

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `android:rotation` refers to the View that is the ImageView, not its contents.

If you want to rotate the contents, either set a new BItmap as content, or override `onDraw()` and rotate the canvas

Comment: If it refers to view, how it happens, that the `View` is not rotated when looking with "Show layout bounds" mode on?