# Can we write text vertically in a textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I would like to write text vertically using a `TextView` in android.
I would like the output to be as shown below

```
T
E
X
T
```

Is this possible without code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical (rotated) label in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. It's really simple, just add `\n` after each character.

Comment: That is a simple way! Thanks. But, is it possible to adjust the spacing between the alphabets in this case?

Comment: By spacing you mean the spacing between the words, right? (For example the phrase "Hello World" has just 1 space) You are talking about this space, right?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I meant the vertical spacing. We can use `lineSpacingMultiplier` property to reduce/increase line spacing. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, glad i could help out! Kindly accept my answer.