# Display textview Chinese characters from top to bottom; right to left

Tags: android

How do you display a textView such that its characters are ordered from top to bottom; right to left? There has to be a better (and less tedious) way than re-ordering all my texts.

For example, the following Chinese text: -

[image]

when displayed in the traditional Chinese calligraphic format (i.e. top-to-bottom/right-to-left), should be: -

[image]

such that

> VERSE1,VERSE2
>   verse3,verse4

becomes

> v V
>   e E
>   r R
>   s S
>   e E
>   3 1
>   , ,
>   v V
>   e E
>   r R
>   s S
>   e E
>   4 2

Rotation is not what i want, because it tilts the text instead of reordering the characters.  Any suggestions is appreciated.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@String/poem_24"
    android:rotation="90"/>
```

[image]

notice that the text is tilted to the sides, rather than displayed upright.

Comment: To show vertically in a text view , please refer these [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7855852/726954) :

Comment: Visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7855852/726954): it Will help you to show vertically in textview